# create tables in all newly created databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

On each new registration, I create a database for each user using PHP. Each database has a set of 8 tables. So I simply want to create those 8 tables for each new user or let's say each time a new database is created.

I cannot use triggers because they can be used only on tables. What else can be done here? Is there something very simple that I am missing?

**Update:** I just found that there are stored procedures as well. Can these stored procedures be used like triggers to check for new database creation and execute?

Comment: I wonder why you would ever want to create a new database per user... Wouldn't it be easier to just have general tables?

Other than that: just have a custom create statement with some PHP-variables. Creating a database on base of a script isn't possible afaik

Comment: Because each user has a different set of users under him. You can consider the user as a company / enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Run the creation scripts after you create the dataabase.  I'm not aware of a "default tables" option in MySQL, as that functionality is easy to replicate and would be very rarely used.

Comment: You already have a trigger, it's when the new database is created.  If you're already creating the database from PHP, you might as well populate it from there as well.  That's really application level functionality, and doesn't belong (and will be easier) to keep out of your data layer.

Comment: I am currently doing it exactly the same way. I read somewhere that implementing the same functionality at server level will reduce the efforts in terms of time and computing, and hence I thought of this. Thanks for your inputs though.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a control database, with a table, call it db_list. Put a trigger on that table to do your housekeeping. (create customer database and setting up grants)

Comment: But this way can I know of new databases if any were added?

Comment: Nope, it works the other way around. insert a row to control.db_list with the name of the new customer, and let the trigger create the database